# creating index with true=any() on postgres and making queries faster

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, indexing

I have one query which cannot be modified but I need to create indexes on them to make it faster.  the query is:

```
select allcommuni0_.assignedto as col_0_0_ 
from communication.vwallcommunication allcommuni0_ 
where (allcommuni0_.projectid in (750))
and true=any (select case when lower(communicat1_.claimnumber)=lower('193') then true else false end from communication.vwclaimdetails communicat1_ 
              where allcommuni0_.communicationviewid=communicat1_.communicationviewid and allcommuni0_.type=communicat1_.type)
              group by allcommuni0_.assignedto limit 100;
```

There are no indexes right now. How to create optimized index with true=any() operator on Postgres?

Comment: Natural index (communicat1_.communicationviewid, allcommuni0_.type=communicat1_.type)

This index can also contain lower(communicat1_.claimnumber) but to utilize this, query should be modified.

Comment: @Kadet let me try with the natural index and observe if there is any improvement. If not, we will try to modify the query as well.

Comment: try `CREATE INDEX vwclaimdetails_lower_claimnumber_idx ON communication.vwclaimdetails (lower(claimnumber));
CREATE INDEX vwallcommunication_projectid_idx ON communication.vwallcommunication (projectid);`

Comment: @mark this is still taking more than 1 second to execute.

Comment: "*query which cannot be modified*" - why not?

Comment: @Kadet Can you please mention the exact columns? I am afraid that I did not understand completely here.

Comment: @Bergi This query is generated by the framework and need not be modified. If only, it cannot be optimized with this pattern, then we will have to raise a change request to modify this.

Comment: @kumarashish Since you mentioned, you use framework. Can you use psql to test the timing?

Comment: @mark Planning Time: 3.472 ms
 Execution Time: 1230.444 ms

Comment: then probably try create index on column type and column communicationviewid.

Comment: @mark you can mark this as an answer. the creation of communicationviewid, type on both tables worked for me.

Comment: @kumarashish Creating that index on the `vwclaimdetails` table should be enough. On the `vwallcommunication` table, you rather want to create an index on the `projectid`.

Answer (score 0):

create an index on column type and column communicationviewid.

```
CREATE INDEX vwclaimdetails_lower_claimnumber_idx ON communication.claimdetails ((CASE
        WHEN communicationoutboundid IS NOT NULL THEN communicationoutboundid
        ELSE communicationinboundid
    END),(CASE
        WHEN communicationoutboundid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Outbound'::text
        ELSE 'Inbound'::text
    END));
```

Comment: I doubt that this expression index would be used by the query you've shown in the question. An index on columns `type` and `communicationviewid` would, though.

Comment: @Bergi type and communicationviewid are the same columns as in the expression index

Comment: @bergi yes it is